# Landscape for single view or some of the views inside tabbar and navigation controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, autorotate

Hi there i have an app looking like this:

```
                   ---- nav conteroller -- viewcontrollers

 TabbarConteroller ---- nav controller -- view controllers

                   ---- nav controller -- view controllers
```

So there is a tabBarController holding navigation controllers and viewcontrollers are embeded on those navigation controllers. how do i make one of view controllers not rotate if other views are rotating or make one of the views rotate while others are on portrait mode.
Some code about subclassing tabbarcontroller and nav controllers would help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your TabBarViewController allows rotate, all your NavigationControllers allow rotate too

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{return YES;}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; }
```

YourViewController which wants to rotate or not:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
// return orientation that you want 
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: If i add the last code u described 
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
// return orientation that you want 
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
on viewcontrollers it doesnt work , do i have to subclass tabcontroller and navcontrollers to write the code above
thanks in advance ...

Comment: I mean that, if childViewController rotates, it depends on father class (Navigation, TabBaB) allow rotate or not. It helps you or not?